# HTTP POST with axios: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: python, http, axios, http.server

I am trying to make a HTTP Post request through axios:

```
    const onSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log("submit", values);
      // ctx.$i18n.locale = "en";
      axios.post("http://192.168.3.2:8081", { // HTTP POST
        name: state.name,
        age: state.age,
        message: state.message,
        canvas: state.canvas,
      });
    };
```

And my backend server is like (Python):

```
class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
    def do_OPTIONS(self):           
        self.send_response(200, "ok")       
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')                
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
        # self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")  
    def do_GET(self):
        logging.info("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(self.path), str(self.headers))
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself      
        logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8'))
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
        f = open(json.loads(post_data.decode('utf-8'))["name"]+ "-" + date.today().strftime("%m-%d-%Y") + ".txt", "w")
        f.write(post_data.decode('utf-8'))
        f.close()
```

I tested my backend server with Postman and it works fine, but it keeps returning this error in browser if I tried it with axios

```
POST http://192.168.3.2:8081/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:84)
```

BTW: in server loggings, it seems like the server never receives a POST request, but only an OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the request created by axios is a promise

you need to chain a `.then` to it for the request to be actually sent

otherwise use the keyword `async / await` in a newer browser

there are some examples in the README file of axios: https://github.com/axios/axios